# Go idiomatic type conversion function naming

Tags: go, naming-conventions

[Effective Go says](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface-names):

> call your string-converter method String not ToString.

I.e., to convert `MyType` to `String`, idiomatic type conversion function naming is `MyType.String()`. So to expand this concept further,

Say I need to serialize `MyType` to and from `JSON`. How should I name my type conversion functions? Of course `MyType` to `JSON` would be `MyType.JSON()`, but how about convert from `JSON` then, how to name such function idiomatically?

Comment: How about [`MarshalJSON`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`UnmarshalJSON`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) ;). Although keep in mind that those are intended for custom json (un)marshaling, the sensible approach would be, in my mind, not to have methods for this at all and just drop your instances into `json.Marshal` and `json.Unmarshal`. Trying to force every functionality into methods is not the way to Go.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `JSON` is not a type. Encoding a data structure using an encoding such as JSON or XML is not type conversion. For JSON, use `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON` methods as defined in the json package documentation so you can use the standard library JSON marshaling and unmarshaling:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/